# How do I run an APK in a device from the Unity IDE without rebuilding the binary?

Tags: android, unity

I know that the button `Build` creates the APK in my disk.

And the button `Build and Run` creates it and sends it to a real device if connected via USB.

**Question:**

Is there any way to "Run" from the Unity IDE an APK in a physical device without having to re-build it (provided you properly built it a few minutes ago, for example?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Unity Remote 5](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.unity3d.mobileremote&hl=en_US&gl=US) allows the Unity editor to send a video stream of the editor's Game tab to your Android device, and responds to touch input like it was the real thing, which is a convenient way to test your touch input. More details [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityRemote5.html).

But if you want to test the APK properly (like if you're testing Google Play API integration or something), you'll have to build and run every time.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to test APIs. So I guess then that no way to re-upload it from the IDE... build everytime.